# Throwing an express custom validator error message inside XMLHttpRequest onreadystatechange function

Tags: node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

I'm using a custom express validator to validate if an URL MIME type is 'image'. It's actually working fine, when I pass a valid image URL it's working. However when I test for an incorrect URL, something seem to be wrong with my `return Promise.reject`. The `mimiHeader` is printing out correctly, it's not an image but when it goes to `else` clause my app is crashing (`npm install --save xmlhttprequest`):

```
router.post('/cast',  [
    body('coverimg','invalid').custom((value, {req})=>{
        if(value!==''){// If there's an imageURL then validate that it's an image URL
            var XMLHttpRequest=require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest
            const xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest()
            xhttp.open('HEAD', value)
            xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if(this.readyState===this.DONE){
                    const mimiHeader=this.getResponseHeader("Content-Type")

                    console.log(mimiHeader) <-- this is printing out correct

                    if(mimiHeader && mimiHeader.substring(0,5)==='image') return Promise.resolve()
                    else return Promise.reject('error - URL is not an image') <-- causing the error
                }
            }
            xhttp.send()
        }
    }),
    body('biography','invalid').isLength({max:10000})
], adminUserController.createCast)
```

[image: Node error encountered]

If I remove the first block resulting in this, it's working and returning error messages without the app crashing so it means the crash is coming from the XMLHttpRequest block:

```
router.post('/cast',  [
    body('biography','invalid').isLength({max:10})
], adminUserController.createCast)
```

I tried putting in a try/catch but same error crash.
Anyone has any ideas with why my `return Promise.reject` is not working in the `XMLHttpRequest onreadystatechange` function?